# Transpose Rows to Column in FME

Tags: fme

how can I Transpose from Row to column?
from this

[image]

[image]

to this

Answer (score 0):

Just add an AttributeCreator where the Attribute Name comes from your "name" attribute and the value from your "value" attribute. Pay attention to the notation @Value(attrName):

[image]

Comment: This answer is incomplete, as for FME 2021.1, it will need adding an AttributeExposer with the name of those attribute on it and an Aggregator.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do that is to use schema with list exploder:

[image]